# cakephp Configuration on ubuntu

Tags: cakephp, ubuntu, configuration

I am using CakePHP with Ubuntu, I tried to config cakephp with ubuntu, but I found this error:

> Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class ImgController
> could not be found.
>
> #0 /var/www/app/webroot/index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))

Has anyone who found a solution for this error?

Thank you

Comment: Does the rest of the site work? Did you also copy/install the lib dir to /var/www/ ? What version of CakePHP are you trying to install on what version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you try to access to a file in img folder who doesn't exist. If you have an image path like

> /img/my_picture.png

ant the file dosen't exist, CakePHP mapped it to the controller img, who doesn't exist, so the error [MissingControllerException]

---

To help you to understand, here what the htaccess does:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And here some doc about the routing http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: Hi, I have try to change in router setting as you have given URL, but I didn't get any result. can you give me more idea, how can i solve this problem

Comment: Like i said, i really think you have a path somewhere to an image who isn't exist. Confirm you have an img folder in your webroot with all the images you need inside. Otherwise, can you say me if it's a clean install of cakePHP? otherwise, can you edit your question with adding some code?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have apache mod_rewrite working?

In order to use mod_rewrite you can type the following command in the terminal:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart apache2 after

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

In your virtualhost add

```
<Directory /var> # change this path for yours
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that running Ubuntu has anything to do with this problem. What is the is the URL you're trying to reach in your browser? Given the error it appears you're trying to reach `http://localhost/img` but you haven't defined `ImgController.php` in your controllers directory?

Answer (score -1):

I get the same error. open your console and refresh the page. 
a image is trying to be loaded but not found. in the console/network debugger you should have a red line with error to load the img.